# How to listen to the window scroll event in a VueJS component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to listen to the window scroll event in my Vue component. Here is what I tried so far:

```
<my-component v-on:scroll="scrollFunction">
    ...
</my-component>
```

With the `scrollFunction(event)` being defined in my component methods but it doesn't seem to work.

Anyone has any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Vue.js event on window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36993834/add-vue-js-event-on-window)

Comment: See https://forum.vuejs.org/t/for-v-on-aspecificevent-is-it-necessary-to-create-destroy-event-listeners/40688/8: "A custom component, as just a calling syntax beacon, is not a component that can emit an event but can forward an event from within it. Only native components can emit a native event."

Comment: In vue3, this works out of the box. No need for any additional code.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Actually I found a solution. I'm adding an event listener on the `scroll` event when the component is created and removing the event listener when the component is destroyed.

```
export default {
  created () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  unmounted () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll (event) {
      // Any code to be executed when the window is scrolled
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if it won't be destroyed? It's gonna work on all pages?

Comment: @AlexanderKim correct. It'll continue firing the method you provided even if the component is no longer visible.

Comment: @AlexanderKim if you are using keep-alive component, and you want this to stop when not active, you should use deactivate instead of destroyed, and use activated instead of created. This could should also use mounted instead of created, as it's not guaranteed to be mounted even if created.

Comment: @jeerbl Can't make this work on my end with vue components am using https://framework7.io/vue

Comment: @jeerbl Is there something else have not done for this to work. Am trying to console something in handleScroll function yet nothing happens.

Comment: I too faced the same problem. nothing happens in HandleScroll method. For vue js suggest any methods.

Comment: @sagusara My answer below might help :)

Comment: it does not refresh the current component. I put the complete answer at the end

Comment: For Nuxt, you need to use beforeMount and beforeDestory since it wont have access to window property. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47327119/how-to-listen-to-scroll-events-in-vue-nuxtjs

Comment: is there any way to use `watch()` from vue 3 to do the task? I've tried but it's not working.

Comment: UPDATE :
the `destroyed()` lifecycle hook is deprecated use `unmounted()`

Comment: v-on is also deprecated

Comment: Why not use mounted instead of created?

Comment: Does it also work with Router View in Vue? For me this solution doesn't work! @jeerbl

Answer (score 52):

In my experience, using an event listener on scroll can create a lot of noise due to piping into that event stream, which can cause performance issues if you are executing a bulky `handleScroll` function.

I often use the technique shown here in the highest rated answer, but I add debounce on top of it, usually about `100ms` yields good performance to UX ratio.

Here is an example using the top-rated answer with Lodash debounce added:

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

export default {
  methods: {
    handleScroll(event) {
      // Any code to be executed when the window is scrolled
      this.isUserScrolling = (window.scrollY > 0);
      console.log('calling handleScroll');
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.handleDebouncedScroll = debounce(this.handleScroll, 100);
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleDebouncedScroll);
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    // I switched the example from `destroyed` to `beforeDestroy`
    // to exercise your mind a bit. This lifecycle method works too.
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleDebouncedScroll);
  }
}
```

Try changing the value of `100` to `0` and `1000` so you can see the difference in how/when `handleScroll` is called.

BONUS: You can also accomplish this in an even more concise and reuseable manner with a library like `vue-scroll`. It is a great use case for you to learn about custom directives in Vue if you haven't seen those yet. Check out https://github.com/wangpin34/vue-scroll.

This is also a great tutorial by Sarah Drasner in the Vue docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/creating-custom-scroll-directives.html

## For Vue 3 users

In vue3 you should use unmounted or beforeUnmount, instead of `beforeDestroy`.

[Lifecycle hook beforeDestroy is not emitted in Vue3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743811/lifecycle-hook-beforedestroy-is-not-emitted-in-vue3)

Comment: Do you really need `lodash` here? Having a `setTimeout` in the `handleScroll` function and clearing the timeout ID if it's not null would do the trick. Anyway, both work but we could avoid the library for 2 lines of code

Comment: My intent was to highlight the difference. It will mostly depend on what exactly is inside your `handleScroll` function and of course how fast the client can execute it. An example of a bad case would be a slow client executing threadblocking code that takes 200ms to execute while `handleScroll` is called every 100ms.

Comment: Note that in vue3 you should use unmounted or beforeUnmount, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743811/lifecycle-hook-beforedestroy-is-not-emitted-in-vue3

Comment: @jeerbl actually the latest lodash will only import exactly that debounce function not the entire library.

Comment: try `npm install --save lodash.debounce`

Answer (score 18):

Here's what works directly with Vue custom components.

```
 <MyCustomComponent nativeOnScroll={this.handleScroll}>
```

or

```
<my-component v-on:scroll.native="handleScroll">
```

and define a method for handleScroll. Simple!

Comment: what the hell is `nativeOnScroll`?

Comment: When working with Vue custom components, if you want initiate any native event say - click, scroll, change- you need to use native with it. onChange or onScroll just won't work. As a simple example imagine a `<MyButton v-on:click="thisWontWork" />` but `<MyButton v-on:click.native="thisWorks" />`

Comment: Yes, `native` event modifier is a must sometimes. I was under impression that `nativeOnScroll` that gets mentioned is something more that just a custom event emitted by child. Sorry

Comment: Thanks so much ! That solution worked way better for me than defining an event listener !

Comment: @kushalvm Could you add full example for `nativeOnScroll`? I assume it is something like `<div @scroll='$emit('nativeOnScroll')>...</div>` inside `MyCustomComponent`. In your answer it gives an impression that it is some built-in Vue event.

Comment: this `v-on:scroll.native` is now depcrecated and triggers the error message `error  '.native' modifier on 'v-on' directive is deprecated  vue/no-deprecated-v-on-native-modifier`

Answer (score 9):

I've been in the need for this feature many times, therefore I've extracted it into a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html). It can be used like this:

```
import windowScrollPosition from 'path/to/mixin.js'

new Vue({
  mixins: [ windowScrollPosition('position') ]
})
```

This creates a reactive `position` property (can be named whatever we like) on the Vue instance. The property contains the window scroll position as an `[x,y]` array.

Feel free to play around with [this CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/kokw326jrv).

Here's the code of the mixin. It's thoroughly commentated, so it should not be too hard to get an idea how it works:

```
function windowScrollPosition(propertyName) {
  return {
    data() {
      return {
        // Initialize scroll position at [0, 0]
        [propertyName]: [0, 0]
      }
    },
    created() {
      // Only execute this code on the client side, server sticks to [0, 0]
      if (!this.$isServer) {
        this._scrollListener = () => {
          // window.pageX/YOffset is equivalent to window.scrollX/Y, but works in IE
          // We round values because high-DPI devies can provide some really nasty subpixel values
          this[propertyName] = [
            Math.round(window.pageXOffset),
            Math.round(window.pageYOffset)
          ]
        }

        // Call listener once to detect initial position
        this._scrollListener()

        // When scrolling, update the position
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this._scrollListener)
      }
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
      // Detach the listener when the component is gone
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this._scrollListener)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Combine this answer with the debounce (found below) and you have a solid solution! Thanks

Comment: @Visualize This depends a lot on what you want to do on scroll. As long as you don't perform very costly tasks, you actually don't even need a debounce — tested on a 3 year old middle-to-lower-end Android phone (Honor 5C) with this demo: https://vue-scroll-fuicczvgsv.now.sh/

Answer (score 7):

I think the best approach is just add ".passive"

```
v-on:scroll.passive='handleScroll'
```

Comment: While valid for the component itself it will only detect scrolling _inside_ the component. If you want to detect **the whole page scroll** you need to use `window.addEventListener`. See other answers.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but I found a better solution with [Vue.js 2.0+ Custom Directives](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html): I needed to bind the scroll event too, then I implemented this.

First of, using `@vue/cli`, add the custom directive to `src/main.js` (before the Vue.js instance) or wherever you initiate it:

```
Vue.directive('scroll', {
  inserted: function(el, binding) {
    let f = function(evt) {
      if (binding.value(evt, el)) {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', f);
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', f);
  }
});
```

Then, add the custom `v-scroll` directive to the element and/or the component you want to bind on. Of course you have to insert a dedicated method: I used `handleScroll` in my example.

```
<my-component v-scroll="handleScroll"></my-component>
```

Last, add your method to the component.

```
methods: {
  handleScroll: function() {
    // your logic here
  }
}
```

You don’t have to care about the Vue.js lifecycle anymore here, because the custom directive itself does.

Comment: TypeError: binding.value is not a function with Vue 2.5.2.

Comment: handleScroll function declaration should contain event and element arguments

Answer (score 4):

What about something like this? This is Vue 3 by the way

```
setup() {
    function doOnScroll(event) {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", doOnScroll);
      console.log("stop listening");
      // your code here ....
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", doOnScroll, { passive: true });
        console.log("start listening");
      }, 500);
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", doOnScroll, { passive: true });
  }
```

The idea here is to listen for the scroll event only once, do your script and then reattach the scroll listener again with a delay in the `setTimeout` function. If after this delay the page is still scrolling the scroll event will be handled again.
Basically the scroll event is listened only once every 500ms (in this example).

I'm using this just to add a css class during the scroll to move away a button.

Answer (score 2):

this does not refresh your component I solved the problem by using Vux
create a module for vuex "page"

```
export const state = {
    currentScrollY: 0,
};

export const getters = {
    currentScrollY: s => s.currentScrollY
};

export const actions = {
    setCurrentScrollY ({ commit }, y) {
        commit('setCurrentScrollY', {y});
    },
};

export const mutations = {
    setCurrentScrollY (s, {y}) {
       s.currentScrollY = y;
    },
};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
};
```

in App.vue :

```
created() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll () {
      this.$store.dispatch("page/setCurrentScrollY", window.scrollY);
      
    }
  },
```

in your component :

```
  computed: {
    currentScrollY() {
      return this.$store.getters["page/currentScrollY"];
    }
  },

  watch: {
    currentScrollY(val) {
      if (val > 100) {
        this.isVisibleStickyMenu = true;
      } else {
        this.isVisibleStickyMenu = false;
      }
    }
  },
```

and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

Vue3 with `<script setup>` working example:

```
<template>
  <header :class="stickyHeader ? 'sticky' : ''" ></header>
<template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onBeforeMount } from 'vue'

onBeforeMount(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
})

const stickyHeader = ref(false)

function handleScroll(){
  if (window.pageYOffset) {
    stickyHeader.value = true
  } else {
    stickyHeader.value = false
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: FYI `pageYOffset` is now deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Vue3, I added the listener on beforeMount, and it works, just if your case like mine, I need the listener to be triggered on the entire app

```
beforeMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
},
methods: {
   handleScroll(){
     // work here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In vue scrolling not a window element. MB in u app will work smth like this:

```
mounted () {
    document.querySelector('.className').addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},

methods: {
    handleScroll(e){
        console.log(this.scrollEl.scrollTop)
    }
},
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    if ((<HTMLInputElement>event.target).id === 'latest-div') { // or any other filtering condition
  
    }
}, true /*Capture event*/);
```

You can use this to capture an event and and here "latest-div" is the id name so u can capture all scroller action here based on the id you can do the action as well inside here.

Answer (score -1):

In combination `this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name` with  and loading on demand, the scroll event is a really useful feature.

Use a trigger. For example, a tab:

```
<v-tabs
  v-bind:grow="!isFullScreen()"
  v-bind:vertical="isFullScreen()"
>
```

Some class attributes:

```
private isUserScrolling: boolean = false;
private isLoaded: boolean = false;
private startScroll: number = 3;
```

Function that reacts to the trigger (adjustment if necessary):

```
private isFullScreen(): boolean {
    switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
      case "xs":
        this.startScroll = 500;
        return false;
      case "sm":
        this.startScroll = 300;
        return false;
      case "md":
        this.startScroll = 100;
        return true;
      case "lg":
        this.startScroll = 50;
        return true;
      case "xl":
        this.startScroll = 3;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Add your event:

```
created() {
   window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}
```

React to your event:

```
private handleScroll(event: any): void {
   this.isUserScrolling = window.scrollY > this.startScroll;
   
   if (this.isUserScrolling && !this.isLoaded) {
     // load your stuff
     ...
     this.isLoaded = true;
   }
}
```