# How to listen to scroll events in vue nuxtjs?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've search for a solution and came up with this code

```
methods: {
  handleScroll () {
    console.log(window.scrollY)
  }
},
created () {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},
destroyed () {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. I also tried to change window to document.body.

The error message was `Window is not defined`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`window` is undefined because nuxt JS is server side rendered.

So try it using `process.client` variable

```
methods: {
  handleScroll () {
    console.log(window.scrollY)
  }
},
created () {
    if (process.client) { 
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }
},
destroyed () {
    if (process.client) { 
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }
}
```

See [link](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/window-document-undefined/) for more info

Comment: I get an error: `Unexpected window in created nuxt/no-globals-in-created`

Comment: ^which comes from the nuxt eslint plugin  
See my answer below.

Comment: Instead of ```process.browser``` now is ```process.client```

Comment: The supplied link is dead. I think this is the place to link to now: https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/concepts/server-side-rendering/

Answer (score 69):

Using `window` or any other browser-specific API in `created` or `beforeCreate` will lead to problems because platform-specific APIs like `document` or `window` are not available on the server (where SSR happens). Instead, move the logic from created into `beforeMount`. Leaving it in created and checking it via `process.browser` would work as well but is not as clean and can lead to confusion easily.

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    handleScroll () {
      // Your scroll handling here
      console.log(window.scrollY)
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
  }
}
```

Only `created` and `beforeCreate` are executed on both sides, server and client. Therefore you don't need guarding ifs in `beforeMount` or `beforeDestroy`.

Further read about [ssr-ready Vue components](https://blog.lichter.io/posts/universal-ssr-vue-component-guide/)

Comment: Great answer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For me work only with 'wheel' not 'scroll'

```
 beforeMount () {
    window.addEventListener('wheel', this.handleScroll)
 },
 
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('wheel', this.handleScroll);
  },
```