# Vue centralize scroll- and resize-events (avoiding repetition in components)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue-structure like this:

```
App
 |--{ data: { scrollInfo {...} } }
 |
 |--Component1
 |      |--{ data: { sidebarWidth: 500 }
 |
 |--Component2
 |      |--{ data: { overlayItemWidth: 389 }
 |
 |--Component3
 ...
 ...
```

In each of my components, I have elements that has variables that should change on scroll and resize (such as `sidebarWidth` or `overlayItemWidth` ). I found this [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45822151/1766219) that shows this way of adding a listener for scroll and resize.

I've added it to the main instance, like so:

```
data: {
  scrollInfo: {
    scrollFromTop: 0,
    viewportHeight: 0,
    viewportWidth: 0,
    pageHeight: 0
  }
},
created() {
  window.addEventListener( 'scroll', this.calculateScroll );
  window.addEventListener( 'resize', this.calculateViewport );
  window.addEventListener( 'resize', this.calculatePageScrollSpecs );
  this.calculateViewport();
  this.calculateScroll();
  this.calculatePageScrollSpecs();
},
destroyed() {
  window.removeEventListener( 'scroll', this.calculateScroll );
  window.removeEventListener( 'resize', this.calculateViewport );
  window.removeEventListener( 'resize', this.calculatePageScrollSpecs );
}
```

I wont show the contents of the methods (`calculateScroll`, `calculateViewport`, ... ), since it's not relevant to this question.

Now... In my components I have variables that should change and reevaluate on scroll and on resize as well. But every time I have such a variable, then I currently add those same listeners in `created` and `destroyed`, and then add the same event-listeners to the given component, and then do the calculations from a new method in there. It seems long and clumbsy.

Are there a way that I can get around having those `window.AddEventListener`s in each component, but only have those in my root instance?

... I was thinking, if I had an array of 'things-that-need-to-be-recalculated-on-scroll-or-resize' in my main instance, but I'm not sure if it would get cluttered, since the variables for the components then actually wouldn't be kept in the component, but instead be referenced with `this.$root.sidebarWidth`. And this would also make my main instance massive.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perfect use case for a [custom directive](https://css-tricks.com/power-custom-directives-vue/), or you could use a [third party](https://github.com/wangpin34/vue-scroll) implementation

Comment: Have you tried mixins?

Comment: Hmm... Ehm... No, - can you give an example of such an implementation?

Comment: Hi, mixins are not the way to go since they don't remove the event duplication problem. You can use Vuex for a dedicated state management (it's basically a global variables manager) but it would maybe be overkill in your case. Your best bet is to calculate your data in App component and pass it as `props` to all the child components. This way they get the same data at the same time and can manipulate it individually.

Comment: is there a reason why you don't use `computed` in your components and just pass `scrollInfo` as a prop?
basically they will watch `scrollInfo` and reevaluate every time it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... No answers at all, - so I dived down into it myself. This is the best I could come up with. I hope it helps others in the need of the same.

I was torn between using `extends` ([source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends)) or `mixins` ([source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mixins)).

After a bit of research, I ended up using mixins ([this video](https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/next-level-vue/mixins/) hit the nail on the head regarding what I was trying to achieve and how to solve it). If you want to make the mixin global, for all components, then look at this video around 4:11 and onwards. I'm *not* doing that in below-written explanation.

Please note, that I'm using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) alongside [laravel-mix](https://laravel-mix.com/) with below-written solution. It's used in a WordPress-installation.

**Disclosure**

This is a mix of a bazillion different answers and articles. It would take forever to credit it all to the correct owners and sources, so I'm not even gonna try. Sorry.

### The mixins-file (`./mixins/scrollAndResize.js`).

```
export const scrollAndResizeMixin = {
  created() {
    console.log( 'scrollAndResizes loaded' );
    this.calcScroll();
    this.calcPageAndViewport();
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      scrollFromTop: 0,
      viewportHeight: 0,
      viewportWidth: 0,
      pageHeight: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    calcScroll: function (){
      let doc = document.documentElement;
      this.scrollFromTop = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);

      // DEBUG (uncomment and scroll, to check if it works)
      // console.log( (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) );
      // console.log( (doc.clientTop || 0) );
    },
    calcPageAndViewport: function(){
      // Viewport info
      this.viewportHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
      this.viewportWidth = Math.min(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);

      // Page length
      var body = document.body;
      var html = document.documentElement;
      this.pageHeight = Math.max(
        body.scrollHeight,
        body.offsetHeight,
        html.clientHeight,
        html.scrollHeight,
        html.offsetHeight
      );
    },

  }
};
```

### The main js-file (`./app.js`).

```
// Vue
import Vue from 'vue';

// Mixins
import { scrollAndResizeMixin } from './mixins/scrollAndResize';

// The Application
const app = new Vue({
  mixins: [
    scrollAndResizeMixin
  ],
  computed: {
    mobile: function() {
      return this.viewportWidth < 992; // This uses the mixin
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', this.calcScroll );
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', this.calcPageAndViewport );
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener( 'scroll', this.calcScroll );
    window.removeEventListener( 'resize', this.calcPageAndViewport );
  }
});
```

### And/or use it only in a component like so...

```
<template>

  <div>
    <p v-if="viewportWidth > 992">
      Desktop
    </p>
    <p v-else>
      Mobile
    </p>   
  </div>

</template>



<script>
  import { scrollAndResizeMixin } from '../mixins/scrollAndResize';

  export default {
    mounted() {
    },
    mixins: [
      scrollAndResizeMixin
    ],
    created() {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.calcScroll);
      window.addEventListener('resize', this.calcPageAndViewport);
    },
    destroyed() {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.calcScroll);
      window.removeEventListener('resize', this.calcPageAndViewport);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: For reference here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-heisenberg-n3q94?file=/src/App.vue) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you found a solution for yourself, but for future visitors who may want a little more comfortable/general solution: I had the same problem some months ago and put a Vue mixin on npm that does exactly this — handling global data once-per-lifetime, not once per mounted component.

It's called [Reactivator](https://github.com/Loilo/vue-reactivator) and this is how you'd create a global handler for `window.resize` with it:

```
// viewport-width.js

export default {
  // Reactivator uses `getInitialState` to fetch the
  // initial value before any listener was attached.
  getInitialState() {
    return window.innerWidth
  },

  // Reactivator calls `listen` when the first component using
  // it is created and executes the returned cleanup callback
  // when it's the last component using it is destroyed.
  listen(set) {
    const resizeHandler = () => set(window.innerWidth)

    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler)

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeHandler)
  }
}


// component.js

import reactivator from 'vue-reactivator'
import viewportWidth from './viewport-width.js'

export default {
  mixins: [
    // `viewportWidth` will now be a reactive property in this component!
    reactivator({ viewportWidth })
  ]
}
```

That said, watching viewport size is such a common case that I have put it (and other useful things like scroll position or mouse position) in an extra package of common Reactivator implementations. You can find it on npm as [`vue-browser-state`](https://github.com/Loilo/vue-browser-state).

Answer (score 0):

You should be making a custom component that can accept as props the things that change and that does all the operations needed (such as adding and removing event listeners).