# Lifecycle hook beforeDestroy is not emitted in Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-dynamic-components

I use vue3 beta 18, found that `beforeDestroy` is not emitted when I remove a component which is rendered by dynamic component in `v-for`.

Neither are deactivated, destroyed.

The component is "disappeared", when I remove it from the collection "windows".

```
<template>
component(v-for="ww in windows" :key="ww.$id" :is="ww.component" v-bind="ww.props")
</template>
```

Comment: Find an explanation of vue3 lifecycle hooks in depth at [Vue 3 lifecycle hooks with real-time example](https://blog.canopas.com/vue-3-lifecycle-hooks-with-real-time-example-1b772b89e085)

Answer (score 38):

In Vue 3 `beforeDestroy` and `destroyed` hooks are replaced with `beforeUnmount` and `unmounted` https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#beforeunmount